# error TS2345: Argument of type 'FlattenMaps' - Typescript Compile failed

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

The compilation of the typescript (npm run build) failing due to nested schema. The step (hubs.push(h.toJSON());) is failing with TS2345 error code. Not sure what is missing, I am trying to upgrade nodejs and mongodb versions. Please help me troubleshoot this issue:

Code step which is failing:
Conntroller trying to collect all the Hubs as a JSON paylod:

```
            const result = org.toJSON();
            const hubs: HubRep[] = [];

            const hs = await Hub.find({ "organization.ref": org._id }, { _id: 1, name: 1 });
            hs.forEach(h => {
             
            
                hubs.push(h.toJSON());
            });
```

The Schema Code:

```
import * as mongoosePaginate from "mongoose-paginate";
import { EntityModel, Entity, entitySchemaHelper, DbRef } from "../../lib/data/entity";
import { Organization, OrganizationModel } from "../../iam/models/organization";
import { CityModel, citySchema } from "./city";

export interface HubRep extends EntityModel {
    name: string;
    displayName: string;
    city: CityModel;
    organization: DbRef<OrganizationModel, "Organization">;
}

export interface HubModel extends HubRep, Entity {
}

const hubSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    displayName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    city: citySchema,
    organization: {
        kind: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            default: "Organization"
        },
        ref: {
            type: String,
            refPath: "organization.kind",
            required: true
        }
    }
}
```

*error TS2345: Argument of type 'FlattenMaps<{ name: string; displayName: string; city: CityModel; organization: DbRef<OrganizationModel, "Organization", string>; _revision?: number; _createdAt?: Date; ... 4 more ...; _version?: number; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HubRep'.
The types of 'city.$assertPopulated' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'FlattenMaps<(<Paths = {}>(paths: string | string[]) => Omit<any, keyof Paths> & Paths)>' is not assignable to type '<Paths = {}>(paths: string | string[]) => Omit<any, keyof Paths> & Paths'.
Type 'FlattenMaps<(<Paths = {}>(paths: string | string[]) => Omit<any, keyof Paths> & Paths)>' provides no match for the signature '<Paths = {}>(paths: string | string[]): Omit<any, keyof Paths> & Paths'*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `h.toJSON()` is returning a `FlattenMaps` but `hubs.push` of type `HubRep[]` is expecting `HubRep`.

To troubleshoot further, it might be worth replacing the `.forEach` with:

```js
const hubJsons = hs.map((hub) => hub.toJSON())
```

Then at least you can look at hubJsons to see what needs doing to turn it into `HubRep[]`